# Custom module block file function is not called

Tags: magento-1.9, php

```
config.xml :

<config>
        <modules>
            <Ndot_Helloworld>
                <version>0.1.0</version>
            </Ndot_Helloworld>
        </modules>
        <global>    
            <blocks>
                <helloworld>
                    <class>Ndot_Helloworld_Block</class>
                </helloworld>
            </blocks>

        </global>
        <frontend>
            <routers>
                <helloworld>
                    <use>standard</use>
                    <args>
                        <module>Ndot_Helloworld</module>
                        <frontName>helloworld</frontName>
                    </args>
                </helloworld>
            </routers>
            <layout>
                <updates>
                    <helloworld module="helloworld">
                        <file>ndot/helloworld.xml</file>
                    </helloworld>
                </updates>
            </layout>
        </frontend>
<config>

helloworld.xml
--------------
<layout version="1.0">
    <helloworld_index_index>
        <reference name="root">
            <action method="setTemplate"><template>page/1column.phtml</template></action> 
        </reference>
        <reference name="content">
            <block type="ndot/helloworld" name="helloworld.custom" template="ndot/helloworld/helloworld.phtml">
            </block>
        </reference>
    </helloworld_index_index>
</layout>

indexControllers:
----------------
class Ndot_Helloworld_IndexController extends Mage_Core_Controller_Front_Action
{
    public function indexAction()
    {
        $this->loadLayout();
        $this->renderLayout();
    }
}

Helloworld.php
-------------
class Ndot_Helloworld_Block_Helloworld extends Mage_Core_Block_Template {

    public function myMessage() {
        echo '=================='; exit;
        return 'I am Iyngaran, This is my module.';
    }

}
```

When i call the myMessage() from the helloworld.phtml but the result is not showing.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have wrongly specify the block type in your file, Call like below

```
<reference name="content">
   <block type="helloworld/helloworld" name="helloworld.custom" template="ndot/helloworld/helloworld.phtml"/>
</reference>
```

In the above code block type is like follow

**first:** helloworld >> the name you have define in the `etc/config.xml` file

i.e:

```
<global>    
   <blocks>
       <helloworld> <!-- Your module block name -->
           <class>Ndot_Helloworld_Block</class>
       </helloworld>
   </blocks>    
</global>
```

**Second(after '/') :** Your block file name.

Comment: i try with your way, but its again no response. can you please share some other answer.

Comment: Could you show your helloworld.phtml

Comment: echo $this->myMessage() this single line only in my helloworld.phtml file, its placed in "magento/app/design/frontend/ndot/english/template/helloworld"

Comment: Ok.did your layout root template change?

Comment: Enable the path hint and check your file rendered or not.

Comment: How to change the layout root template ? can you please explain it.

Comment: You have already did that. Page/1column.phtml

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/22600/discussion-between-senthil-and-meenakshi-sundaram-r).

Comment: thanks for your help, i did the mistake the place of my view file, now i find that and its working. from your answer i learned the concept of of block type.